# Partial parameter documentation

Tags: c++, c, doxygen

I believe that code should be as self-documenting as possible; the purpose of entities (variables, classes,...) should be clear from their name and/or type. In those cases where this self-documentation is sufficient, adding explicit documentation is distracting and should be avoided, I believe.

For example, in the function

```
int max(int a, int b);
```

there really is no need to document the arguments; it is very clear from the signature what they mean.

Of course, self-documentation is not always fully possible and there are cases where some of a function's arguments require explicit documentation.

Unfortunately, doxygen issues warnings for undocumented parameters. At first sight, it may seem that the [WARN_NO_PARAMDOC](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_warn_no_paramdoc) configuration option can help. However, it will only disable warnings if *all* parameters are undocumented. If some are documented and some not, doxygen issues a warning.

So, I have a couple of questions:

- Why does doxygen have this behaviour? Am I maybe wrong in my believe that only parameters that are not self-documenting should be explicitly documented?
- Is there a workaround? (Short of adding empty `\param` statements.)

Comment: There is no right or wrong here, people have differing opinions about things. Personally I would lean towards documenting everything as in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) style, its by far the best reference I've seen.

Comment: If given a function where the parameters are named `a` and `b`, it is quite unclear what they do. This is not really self-documenting, better names would have been `obj1`, `obj2` or similar. Furthermore, a function named `max` is not self-documenting. Does it return the largest of the values? What if they are the same?  Does it return the largest value that something can have? Does it "maximize" something based on `a` and `b`?  Why would someone write a function for something so simple such as `if(a > b) return a; else return b;` And so on. Some brief documentation _is_ necessary.

Comment: @Lundin: You're correct that some documentation would be necessary. My point was that, given a documentation string like "Returns the maximum of two integers", it would be quite clear that `a` and `b` are those integers and do not need explicit documentation.

Comment: My guess: The thinking/discussion about whether a function is self-documenting or not is usually longer than just writing a trivial documentation. (I prefer the latter as this shows to the reader that the function is as trivial as it looks.)

Comment: Btw. what's trivial is not an "exact science"...

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I don't use such documentation tools. If the programmer gets constantly prompted to write documentation in various places, they'll get fed up and write something like `int a`: "the integer variable a" which is of course completely useless info.

Comment: @Lundin: Well that's exactly the reason I don't want those warnings. The problem is that all other Doxygen warnings seem to be perfectly valid so I don't want to disable them completely.

Comment: @Lundin: "*If the programmer gets constantly prompted to write documentation in various places, they'll get fed up and write something like*" And then you *fire them*. If a programmer can't be bothered to do route drudge work correctly, then how can you expect them to slog through whatever project they need to do?

Comment: @NicolBolas If you force someone to use a "quality" tool which leads to nothing but bureaucracy, then these situations happen. Situations often caused by naive, incompetent management who don't understand how humans work. In order to force code documentation, you should rather state rules for how it must be done and add them to your company coding standard. And the best way to find lack of source code documentation is not through some tool but through peer review. Particularly when the project is mostly done and nobody can make excuses about not having enough time for it.